# Suppose that $a_k$ are positive and decreasing. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k)$ if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{2^ka_{2^k}}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [proving cauchy condensation test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260111/proving-cauchy-condensation-test)

Suppose that $a_k$ are positive and decreasing. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k)$ if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{2^ka_{2^k}}$ converges.

By using decreasing how can I prove this?

Comment: @experimentX it has to have the word converges two times

Answer (score 4):

This is the [Cauchy Condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for convergence. Wikipedia has a decent page on it, and it is also covered in many textbooks that cover convergence of series.